# Why doesn't Blender support OpenCL on NVidia cards?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, opencl

I saw the existing question [Why doesn't Blender detect RTX 2060 with OpenCL?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181513/why-doesnt-blender-detect-rtx-2060-with-opencl) but it does not really answer this question but just stating that it does not support it. I would like to know why. OpenCL is an open standard, so it is not manufacturer-specific, is it? I would probably choose OptiX even if OpenCL were available, but why doesn't Blender even give an option to use OpenCL when the card is Nvidia? There shouldn't be extra work for the developers to support OpenCL on Nvidia, is there?

Comment: Seems to be supported: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135014/31447 (can not test that right now), limited to 10 GPU's though, for whatever reason. In my experience OptiX is faster anyway...